# linebreak inside iosMath

Tags: ios, objective-c, latex

I am using `iosmath` for displaying math equations inside my ios application.

**how can i insert linebreak inside `\text{}`**

my code is :

```
label.latex = @"\\text{\(Highest degree=a \\ \newline \linebreak power \ of\ x^2\ is\ 2 \\ sum=6= a+2 \\ therefore\ a= 4\)}";
```

And none of the `\\` , `\newline` , `\linebreak` works

Answer (score 0):

Just use `\n`

For example:

```
label.latex = @"\\text{\(Highest degree=a \n power \ of\ x^2\ is\ 2 \\ sum=6= a+2 \\ therefore\ a= 4\)}";
```

Answer (score 0):

If not inside `\\text{}` use `\\\\`.